# Postfix Mail Server. Someone is sending Mails from my server

Tags: server, security, postfix, mail

I am receiving Mails from my own mail server, from a user that belongs to my domain, but is not listed in my mail user db. Here are the logs:

```
    4679 Mar 28 15:54:13 Bumblebee postfix/smtpd[29350]: connect from unknown[45.127.40.218]
4680 Mar 28 15:54:13 Bumblebee postfix/smtpd[29350]: C7B8A3FCB1EC: client=unknown[45.127.40.218]
4681 Mar 28 15:54:14 Bumblebee postfix/cleanup[29353]: C7B8A3FCB1EC: message-id=<aefdede6748149d6e1f3@mydomain.com>
4682 Mar 28 15:54:14 Bumblebee postfix/qmgr[14800]: C7B8A3FCB1EC: from=<nadiam1pa@mydomain.com>, size=5170, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
4683 Mar 28 15:54:14 Bumblebee postfix/smtpd[29350]: disconnect from unknown[45.127.40.218]
4684 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/smtp[29349]: connect to example.com[2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:25: Connection timed out
4685 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/smtpd[29363]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
4686 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/smtpd[29363]: 875153FCB201: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
4687 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/cleanup[29353]: 875153FCB201: message-id=<aefdede6748149d6e1f3@mydomain.com>
4688 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/smtpd[29363]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
4689 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/qmgr[14800]: 875153FCB201: from=<nadiam1pa@mydomain.com>, size=5957, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
4690 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee amavis[28484]: (28484-11) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [45.127.40.218]:54919 [45.127.40.218] <nadiam1pa@mydomain.com> -> <admin@mydomain.com>, Queue-ID: C7B8A3FCB1EC, Message-ID: <aefdede6748149d6e1f3@mydomain.com>, mail_id: 0r59-HfxT3Vu, Hits     : 5.282, size: 5170, queued_as: 875153FCB201, 1437 ms
4691 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/smtp[29355]: C7B8A3FCB1EC: to=<admin@mydomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.8, delays=0.36/0/0/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 875153FCB201)
4692 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/qmgr[14800]: C7B8A3FCB1EC: removed
4693 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/lmtp[29364]: 875153FCB201: to=<admin@mydomain.com>, relay=mydomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.17, delays=0.06/0/0/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <admin@mydomain.com> 2Hz6JIc3+Va1cgAA4FbCCg Saved)
4694 Mar 28 15:54:15 Bumblebee postfix/qmgr[14800]: 875153FCB201: removed
```

There is no "nadiam1pa" user, I checked several times, but somehow this guy uses my mail server to deliver mails with suspicious attachments to other mail users on my server. I don't know where to start at, to fix this security issue. Can someone help me out with that?

//edit:
Here is the mail header:

```
X-Spam-Level: *****
Return-Path: <nadiam1pa@mydomain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Thread-Index: AdCh6FNHn/LWax1JSTSc7XL2c2t2TQ==
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at mydomain.com
Message-Id: <aefdede6748149d6e1f3@mydomain.com>
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
X-Spam-Score: 5.282
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Status: No, score=5.282 tagged_above=2 required=6.31 tests=[BAYES_20=-0.001, DOS_OUTLOOK_TO_MX=2.845, HELO_MISC_IP=0.25, PYZOR_CHECK=1.392, RDNS_NONE=0.793, SPF_FAIL=0.001, TO_EQ_FM_DOM_SPF_FAIL=0.001, TVD_SPACE_RATIO=0.001] autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0042_01D0A1F9.171F24B0"
Delivered-To: <admin@mydomain.com>
Content-Language: en-US
Received: from mydomain.com by Ubuntu-1310-saucy-64-minimal (Dovecot) with LMTP id 2Hz6JIc3+Va1cgAA4FbCCg for <admin@mydomain.com>; Mon, 28 Mar 2016 15:54:15 +0200
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 875153FCB201 for <admin@mydomain.com>; Mon, 28 Mar 2016 15:54:15 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from mydomain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id 0r59-HfxT3Vu for <admin@mydomain.com>; Mon, 28 Mar 2016 15:54:14 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from [45.127.40.218] (unknown [45.127.40.218]) by mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id C7B8A3FCB1EC for <admin@mydomain.com>; Mon, 28 Mar 2016 15:54:13 +0200 (CEST)
Document (1).pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mail server isn't sending anything. That address is being spoofed. If you check the headers from one of the suspect messages, you'll see the IP address of the sender. Chances are each message you got will have a differing IP address though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the mail header to my question. How do you see, that the mail is not sent by my server? I thought the line "Received: from mydomain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost" indicates, that it actually is sent by my server?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. There is a spoof that sends email with the name of the account owner, with an attachment that contains malicious software (java script file) that is programmed to decrypt the data or damage the position, most of the antivirus does not detect the virus,

Solution

The solution is to protect the outgoing email with DKIM